# Turtle graphics - How do I control when the window closes?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, window-management

I have a small python script which draws some turtle graphics. When my script has finished running, the turtle screen automatically closes, so to be able to see the graphics for a while I have to use `time.sleep(5)` at the end of the script to delay the closing.

Is there any way I can make this more dynamic, i.e. tell python that I want to control the closing of the window myself? I don't mind if the script can't do anything else while waiting for my command, but I'd prefer if I didn't have to go to the console for a `read()` or something. Ideally, the canvas should stay open even after the script finishes running, but I am OK with a solution that halts the script until I close the window that holds the canvas (or click the canvas, or whatever...).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: python -i script.py works from terminal

Comment: This question and answers are valid for turtle programs written in PyCharm as well!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just use [`turtle.done()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.done) or [`turtle.Screen().exitonclick()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.exitonclick) as a last command of your turtle program.

Comment: `import turtle; turtle.exitonclick()` should be enough in Python 3.

Comment: Though there are links it would be better to put a bit of explanation there, too.

Comment: What's the difference between `turtle.done()` and `turtle.Screen().exitonclick()`?

Comment: @Stevoisiak `exitonclick` automatically exits on click but `done` doesn't.

Answer (score 27):

```
import turtle

turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
# etc.

turtle.getscreen()._root.mainloop()  # <-- run the Tkinter main loop
```

(edit: `turtle.done()` as suggested by hua below is less ugly.)

Comment: Perfect! The script halts until I close the window, and then continues.

Comment: Do you need the getscreen()._root part? turtle.mainloop() works well (in Python 3)...

Answer (score 12):

simply use the mainloop() function imported from turtle's module itself!.

```
import turtle


#Draw a square
for i in range(4):
    turtle.forward(200)
    turtle.left(90)


#calling for the mainloop()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'mainloop'` [PAG's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6240234/4794) seems to work fine.

Comment: @DonKirkby   its turtle.mainloop() not Turtle.mainloop()

Comment: You're right, @DevX, not sure how I got that wrong. This answer works for me now.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `input()` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This waits for several clicks - and draws a spiral while you click  - until it decides to exit on the last click:

```
import turtle


win = turtle.Screen()
win.bgcolor("white")

tess = turtle.Turtle()

tess.speed(0)
tess.color("blue")             
tess.pensize(5)                 
offSet=30

def doNextEvent(x,y):

    global offSet
    global win
    tess.forward(20)
    tess.left(1+offSet)
    offSet=offSet-2
    if(offSet<1):
        win.exitonclick()


win.onclick(doNextEvent)
win.listen()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: No it doesn't: `AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'mainloop'`