# Turtle does not run more than once in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics

I am trying to run some turtle code in jupyter notebook. When I run the code once, the code runs fine. However, if I run the code again, Python Turtle Graphics freezes and closes (aka python turtle graphics is not responding) and the jupyter notebook's kernel crashes

I have tried to switch notebooks, reinstalling jupyter and restarting the kernel, but none of them worked.

Here is the turtle code:

```
import turtle
pen = turtle.Pen()
window = turtle.Screen()
pen.color("light blue")
pen.shape("turtle")
pen.forward(100)

window.exitonclick()
```

Here is the error message when I run the code for the second time. The note book is saved at C:\Users\fligh\OneDrive\Jupyter Notebooks\ and the file name is "Principles 2 Playground":

```
<ipython-input-2-79042881c88e> in <module>
      1 import turtle
----> 2 pen = turtle.Pen()
      3 window = turtle.Screen()
      4 pen.color("light blue")
      5 pen.shape("turtle")

c:\users\fligh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\turtle.py in __init__(self, shape, undobuffersize, visible)
   3814                            shape=shape,
   3815                            undobuffersize=undobuffersize,
-> 3816                            visible=visible)
   3817 
   3818 Pen = Turtle

c:\users\fligh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\turtle.py in __init__(self, canvas, shape, undobuffersize, visible)
   2555         self._undobuffersize = undobuffersize
   2556         self.undobuffer = Tbuffer(undobuffersize)
-> 2557         self._update()
   2558 
   2559     def reset(self):

c:\users\fligh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\turtle.py in _update(self)
   2658             return
   2659         elif screen._tracing == 1:
-> 2660             self._update_data()
   2661             self._drawturtle()
   2662             screen._update()                  # TurtleScreenBase

c:\users\fligh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\turtle.py in _update_data(self)
   2644 
   2645     def _update_data(self):
-> 2646         self.screen._incrementudc()
   2647         if self.screen._updatecounter != 0:
   2648             return

c:\users\fligh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\turtle.py in _incrementudc(self)
   1290         if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
   1291             TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
-> 1292             raise Terminator
   1293         if self._tracing > 0:
   1294             self._updatecounter += 1

Terminator:
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a recurrent problem with Jupyter/iPython

You can install [iPyTurtle](https://github.com/gkvoelkl/ipython-turtle-widget) that's should help a lot.
Found on this [medium article](https://medium.com/@jiyuanli93/how-to-make-python-turtle-works-in-jupyter-notebook-6c506b9a973f)

You can also create a file containing your commands using `%%file turtle_example.py` in top of cell and in cell below, then run it using `!python turtle_example.py`.
But this is not really great

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the turtle module multiple times in Jupyter try turtle.bye() at the end:

```
import turtle

bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.forward(50)
turtle.done()

try:
    turtle.bye()
except:
    print("bye")
```

(I added try/except because .bye() raises an Terminator Error)

Based on [turtle.done() not working in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294665/turtle-done-not-working-in-spyder/43297726#43297726)

Comment: This fixed the problem for me (and allows to work with the turtle module only!).

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too! Try:

$ pip install ipyturtle

$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyturtle

---

In the setup.py file, in lines 74 & 75, change

os.path.join(here, 'ipyturtle', 'static', 'extension.js'),

os.path.join(here, 'ipyturtle', 'static', 'index.js')

to

os.path.join(here, 'js', 'lib', 'extension.js'),

os.path.join(here, 'js', 'lib', 'index.js')

---

$ pip install -e .

$ jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix ipyturtle

$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyturtle

---

Should say 'Successfully installed ipyturtle' at the end

Answer (score 0):

ipyturtle seems to not work with JupyterLab or VS Code. Try ipyturtle3.
With python3.6+:

```
python -m pip install ipyturtle3
```

Try the examples listed in this repo:
https://github.com/williamnavaraj/ipyturtle3

https://pypi.org/project/ipyturtle3/

I found this to work in JupyterLab and VSCode