# Can't run turtle on jupyter notebook (turtle graphic window not responding)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics

### First Question

I was doing an example from ThinkPython 2e Chapter 4 Case Study: Interface Design, when I stumbled upon turtle module.

I use jupyter notebook as an IDE to do exercise. Here's the code

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
```

When I ran the code above, the code is exected but Python Turtle Graphic failed to run *with 'Not Responding' status*

The same goes for this, although when I ran the following, the kernal is busy for a while before stating an error

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)
turtle.mainloop()
```

What caused this error?

### Second Question

Then I tried the next code which is

```
bob.fd(100)
```

and it just froze so I have to interrupt the code, here's the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a3ce06f254ac> in <module>
      2 bob = turtle.Turtle()
      3 print(bob)
----> 4 turtle.mainloop()

~\Anaconda3\lib\turtle.py in mainloop()

~\Anaconda3\lib\turtle.py in mainloop(self)
    811 
    812         """
--> 813         TK.mainloop()
    814 
    815     def textinput(self, title, prompt):

~\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in mainloop(n)
    558 def mainloop(n=0):
    559     """Run the main loop of Tcl."""
--> 560     _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
    561 
    562 getint = int

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

#### What I have tried

I've tried to refer to this thread
[Turtle does not run more than once in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56581957/turtle-does-not-run-more-than-once-in-jupyter-notebook)
which eventually leads me back to here

> https://medium.com/@jiyuanli93/how-to-make-python-turtle-works-in-jupyter-notebook-6c506b9a973f

or here

> https://github.com/gkvoelkl/ipython-turtle-widget

a little information : when I run this on my Anaconda prompt

```
$ jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix ipyturtle
$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipyturtle
```

It generated some problems, but ran perfectly (it's said `validating: ok`) when I ran them as admin

any help would be appreciated, I've been stuck with this stuff for 2.5 hours

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem as you.

This worked for me.

Put the following code into three Jupyter Notebook cells:

Cell 1

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)
```

Cell 2

```
for i in range(4):
    bob.fd(100)
    bob.lt(90)
```

Cell 3

```
turtle.mainloop()
```

And run it one by one.

I am a noob, like you, but what I think is happening is that the code `turtle.mainloop()` terminates the object bob, or something like that. What you should do is execute all the movements like `bob.fd(100)` before executing  `turtle.mainloop()`. Does it make sense?