# PyCharm Run Window Automatically Closes After It Finishes Running Code

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

my run window closes automatically in PyCharm after running the Python Turtle programming, but I would like the window to remain open. Is there a way?

Right now I need to enter " input() " at the end of the script to prevent the window from automatically closing. But I hope there is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turtle graphics - How do I control when the window closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234798/turtle-graphics-how-do-i-control-when-the-window-closes)

Comment: @Eliahu Aaron, Thanks. Is there a way which does not require adding an additional line of code at the end of the program, in order for the run window to not automatically close after running a program?