# PyCharm automatically closes pop-up windows, can I stop this?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, turtle-graphics

I am rather new to using PyCharm by JetBrains, but I am just messing around with tkinter and turtle-graphics and whenever I run some code for example:

```
t = turtle.Pen()
t.forward(50)
```

PyCharm will successfully create a turtle window and draw the line, however, the window opened just closes instantly. The same goes if I use tkinter.

Is there anyway to stop PyCharm doing this, and keep the window open?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turtle graphics - How do I control when the window closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234798/turtle-graphics-how-do-i-control-when-the-window-closes)

Comment: in `turtle` similar to `tkinter` you should run `mainloop()` in last line.

Comment: Awesome, this solved my problem thanks @furas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `turtle` which is built on top of `tkinter` you should run `mainloop()` in last line like in `tkinter`

Turtle:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Pen()
t.forward(50)

turtle.mainloop()
```

Tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text='Close', command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It gets key/mouse events from system and send to widgets, check pressed buttons, etc. - so it keeps window open till you press closing button.