# Why does the graphic window not open?

Tags: python, python-turtle

What are the minimum system requirements for Python while running functions of turtle? When I run  -

```
import turtle 
wn = turtle.Screen()
```

the graphics window is not opening.

Comment: Python version? Operating System?

Comment: You program is exiting immediately, perhaps before the window ever became fully visible.  Put `turtle.mainloop()` at the end to keep the window active.

Comment: Roim    windows 10, 3.7.4

Comment: yes   adding  turtle.mainloop() helps . thank you.   will revert if any other issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle graphics - How do I control when the window closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234798/turtle-graphics-how-do-i-control-when-the-window-closes)